# are there any synchronization utilities as a part of C standard?

Tags: c, thread-safety

I'm working on some code for a university assignment, where we were asked to use API available in c++ standard for our thread management.  It was also implied that if there exists standardized C API we are free to use that. Sadly, as far as I researched, there is no cross platform sync API for C and all the examples i saw used either UNIX or windows API.

Hopefully someone who had more experience with C can tell me a cross platform thread sync API is a part of any C standart.

Comment: C and C++ both have standard thread libraries with mutexes and condition variables (though it never really caught on with C; most people just kept on using pthreads).

Comment: @Shawn, I'm aware those exist for cpp, could you name which ones are for C?

Comment: Any decent standard C reference will cover it.

Comment: [Concurrency support library (since C11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)

Comment: @Shawn _most people just kept on using pthreads_ in fact `gcc` use the pthread library behind the scene when you `#include <thread.h>`

Comment: I imagine most implementations use the native threading API behind the scenes. The point of standardising the library is just to allow portability.

Comment: *"we were asked to use API available in c++ standard for our thread management"*, can you elaborate why you don't want to use C++, then?  You can still write C-like code otherwise, or even just put the business logic in .c files, if you want to practice C skills.

Comment: @hyde, I want to specialize in embedded after finishing my bachelor's so i want to maximize using C and doing most stuff myself rather then using very sophisticated libraries

Comment: Are you sure your embedded platforms will _have_ multiple cores? If not, spending extra effort on C concurrency is of questionable use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the [Concurrency support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) introduced in C11, but it's optional.

I can't think of a good reason to use that instead of C++, whose concurrency library is *not* optional and which gives you RAII helpers like `std::unique_lock`, unless you really have to.

This is probably a good time to invest in an up-to-date book, or practice using reference materials and searching - I've never used this library, and it took me seconds to find.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly this is indeed optional. I also saw people mentioning couple times

Comment: Well, it's the only "cross platform thread sync API" that is part of the language standard. pthreads are part of the POSIX standard. What other standard did you have in mind?